# The function matfile is not working?

Tags: matlab

So I have a huge dataset that I am working with, but it takes too much memory. I tried using the `matfile` function on my computer, but it does not exist. Do you guys know how I can use this function. This is the function I am talking about: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html

Also, can you access struct with this function. So let's say I have an object called `model`. Is it possible to access the struct, `model(1)`, with `matfile`?

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: MATLAB Version 7.12.0.635 (R2011a)
MATLAB License Number: STUDENT

Answer (score 5):

Matfile is a function which was introduced with R2011b. You are using R2011a, matfile is not available. I recommend to use the local documentation instead of the online documentation, which matches the features of your matlab version.

Comment: Okay. where exactly can I find that?